# What is a "slap week"?

Tags: meaning

The term is used in Harper Lee's *Go Set A Watchman*, in the following passage. The context is that Jean Louise has been preparing for the big dance at the high school; the referent for "them" in the first paragraph, although irrelevant to the meaning of the expression, is a set of falsies:

> As Jean Louise handed them over, a sudden thought rooted her to the spot. “Oh golly,” she whispered.
>
> “What’s the matter now?” said Calpurnia. “You’ve been fixin’ for this a slap week. What did you forget?”
>
> “Cal, I don’t think I know how to dance.”

Comment: Perhaps *good* as in *an entire week*,  *a whole week*, but I can't confirm this. *Slap* and *slap-up* used to mean *exactly* or *excellent*, so I'm just guessing by analogy with *good*. It seems to fit the context, but some other meaning might also fit.

Comment: Chapter 19 of To Kill a Mockingbird (by the same author) has this: *“I say where the chillun?” [Tom] continued, “an‘ [Miss Mayella] says—she was laughin’, sort of —she says they all gone to town to get ice creams. She says, ‘took me a **slap year** to save seb’m nickels, but I done it. They all gone to town.’”* (ht @dwwheelock).

Answer (score 3):

*Slap* appears to be a regionalism used in the American South meaning the entirety of something, which can be used to emphasize a magnitude of difficulty, achievement, and so on. I have not found it in dialect or slang dictionaries, but it does turn up online in various places:

> It was a slap year before it quit hurting.[[1](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=696041)]
>
> I make sure every product page has a unique title and meta description. Took me a slap month to write them for 2500 products on one site, but I did it. [[2](https://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4422272.htm)]
>
> It took him a slap hour to total up the numbers.[[3](https://weswaincott.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/33/)]
>
> Remember, these are sneaky, underhanded, devious people who kept the Barnes flag deal under wraps for a slap YEAR.[[4](http://www.confederateamericanpride.com/dixieflags-realGAflag.html)]
>
> I've been waiting on this for a slap hour! [[5](https://www.democraticunderground.com/discuss/duboard.php?az=view_all&address=132x8223017)]

*It took me a slap month to finish* reads to me much as *it took me an entire month to finish* or perhaps *it took me literally a month to finish*, and indeed it reads as such when it appears in Harper Lee's earlier work, *To Kill a Mockingbird*, spoken by Tom Robinson quoting Mayella Ewell in testimony:

> Mr. Finch, I was wonderin' why it was so quiet like, an' it come to me that there weren't a chile on the place, not a one of 'em, and I said Miss Mayella, where the chillun? … [A]n' she says — she was laughin', sort of — she says they all gone to town to get ice creams. She says, 'took me a slap year to save seb'm nickels, but I done it. They all gone to town.'

Examples of time were the easiest to find in a web search, but they are far from the exclusive or dominant use. For example, *Southern Living* magazine notes the expression *[worn slap out](http://www.southernliving.com/travel/southern-sayings)* meaning a state of total exhaustion—

> a physical and mental state a few degrees past weary and just this side of dog-tired.

To be *[tore slap up](https://matadornetwork.com/life/26-funniest-southern-expressions-use/)* is to be seriously damaged, injured, or impaired, as *torn up* might be used in a more standard English; [a miner](https://books.google.com/books?id=CJCSCwAAQBAJ) in a William W. Johnston novel had *one ear tore slap off*.

The OED does not list this sense under any definition of *slap*, but I could see it arising out of its adverbial senses of *straight* or *directly* or *suddenly*. A *slap day* is one without interruption, after all. OED examples of this meaning are attested from 1829:

> I, and my Noah's Ark, lay slap in the way.

Comment: FYI. Another possible source for this sense to arise from is "slapping" and "slashing" meaning "very large". These are attested by the 1887 "Encyclopaedic Dictionary". To my ear they are close kin to "strapping", meaning "large", "strong", or "robust", as in "strapping lad". Online Etymology Dictionary suggests that "present-participle adjectives of violent action" (e.g., "whopping, spanking, bouncing") are commonly repurposed to mean something large. And to go from "slapping = large/robust" to "slap = full/complete" is perhaps a short journey.

Answer (score 0):

A slap week, or formerly slapcor in Danish, refers to a four or five day period that may feel like an entire week. Longing and excruciating waiting is involved with a slapcor.

Comment: Interesting! How did you find this out?

Comment: Do you have references?